# Whats the right program for me?

Tags: c++, 2d

I would like to learn C++ so I can get a job in the game industry, but there are so many options it a little confusing. I know most of you will say I should read up on C++ before attempting to program it but I learn best by doing things rather then reading. That being said I don't understand some of the thing suggested on other questions, because I've read a few trying to find whats right for me, so putting things in the simplest terms would be helpful. I've been making a couple of games 2d using gamemaker and if theres a C++ equivalent that would be perfect, but if not possible I would like an IDE that allows me to  easily continue making 2d games, and is fairly simple to learn. Having a 2d sprite editor would be a nice plus but I can understand if its not every thing I want in one program

Comment: _"Most of you will say I should read up on C++ before attempting to program it but I learn best by doing things rather then reading."_ The thing is: you're meant to read, _and then also do_. Almost nobody learns programming just by reading. They follow tutorials, but _they do the programming involved_. Then they program more, do research, program more, etc - that's how everyone learns C++. Or do you want to learn how C++ works without ever reading about it?

Comment: So, yeah, you _should_ read up on C++. There's no other way to really learn it without first reading about it. But don't just read and let that be the end of it: read and _do things_ with what you've read about.

Comment: Sorry, but "how do I get started" questions are not appropriate for the format of this site.

Answer (score 3):

I should suggest Cocos2d-x and Unity for you.

> **Cocos2d-x**

It is based on C++ (as you would like to learn C++). It is simple, easy to learn and has multi-platform support.

Cocos2d-x is a multi-platform 2D game engine in C++, based on cocos2d-iphone and licensed under MIT. Now this engine has been expanded to iOS, Android, Bada, BlackBerry, Marmalade and desktop operating systems like Linux, WindowsXP & Windows7.

- iOS: stable, well tested on iOS 4.x ~ 5.x SDK.
- Android: stable, well tested on 2.0~4.0, based on ndk r5 ~ r8.
- Bada: stable on Bada SDK 1.0 & 2.0
- BlackBerry Playbook & BB10: stable, contribued by engineers working
  at RIM
- Marmalade: stable since cocos2d-x-0.11.0
- Windows: stable, tested on WinXP, Vista, Win7. Please upgrde the
  drive of your video card if you meet problems on OpenGL functions
- Linux: usable.

**Project Resource**

- http://www.cocos2d-x.org/
- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

**Tutorials**

- http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Tutorials
- http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/tutorials-cocos2d-game-tutorials-converted-to-cross-platform-c-cocos2d-x/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/11338/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-space-game

**Community Resource**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711047/the-completest-cocos2d-x-tutorial-guide-list

> **Unity**

If you want a better **IDE** and **everything in one program**, then i should suggest [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

Unity is a cross platform game engine and IDE developed by Unity Technologies, targeting web plugins, desktop platforms and mobile devices.

**Project Resource**

- http://unity3d.com/

**Tutorials**

- http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/
- http://unitygems.com/

Comment: i should add i would like it to be free. Dont you need to buy unity?

Comment: @andyphillips20, Unity has 2 version (free and pro). If you need to learn, you can use the free one. When you want more for example features, publish, then you have to buy.

Comment: I want to personally vouch for cocos2d-x. It's very good.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you start with Python instead of C++.

Why?

If you go the Python route you just start programming - it's a mature language, it's interpreted and widely used in the game industry.

You basically write code and run it. And modify and run it.

With C++, however, you write code, compile, fix errors, link, fix more errors and finally - if you're lucky - you run your program. Really a lot of extra complexity, even for the simplest of programs.
You will not only have to fight the language itself, but also spend a lot of time on learning to use the development tools (IDE, etc.)

First you need to learn how to program - and not only that, but also algorithms, good software design, etc.

Python is a more direct and immediate way to program.
Definitely more joyful than with C++.

You can learn C++ later, but in the meantime check out:

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) or [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) for 2D game programming.

And then perhaps Panda3D or PythonOgre for 3D programming.

And, once you got some solid programming skills, you'd be ready to move to C++.

Python or Java is what you learn in introductory computer science classes. Sometimes it's C, but almost never C++. C++ is a powerful tool, I just can't recommend it as your first real programming language.

Python is also extremely well documented - just type help(object) into the Python shell. Another reason to go with Python.
It's also the fastest growing language currently.
ANd as of October 2012, Python ranks at position 8 in the TIOBE Programming Community Index.

Comment: I don't really agree with this - although python is a great language it's not quite that mature and doesn't have any (established) engines. Beside, the question specifically specified c++. (I'm not the downvote I see just appeared but I thought I'd share my thoughts.)

Comment: He really didn't ask specifically for C++ - he asked how to get into the game industry.

Comment: What do you mean 'established engines'? Max and Maya has Python scripting, Ubisoft hires Python programmers - especially for the content pipeline. Panda3D is a good open source engine for Python. And I didn't say that he shouldn't learn C++. Does he want to get into the industry, or would he prefer to learn C++ first (and definitely die trying) :)

Comment: @jacmoe Elaborating on why C++ is the most difficult programing language and python is perfect for him would make your answer a lot more helpful. Although, I tend to disagree with both your opinions.

Comment: There is a reason why Python (and Java) is widely used as the language you learn in introductory computer science courses. Instead of C++. I've been programming in C++ for a long time, and the language doesn't really get any easier - just new levels of complexity. Well, I don't really care much what he chooses to be honest. The language is not that important - good software engineering skills are.

Comment: Is my post better now? ;)